# reactjs data mapping, get data from server

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, render, database-server

I'm new reactjs
I'm trying to save data that I got from server like **object(array)** but I can't.

[image: demo]

at render() function, what should I do to save data, I don't wanna display, just save to **users (array)** or something? I think that I should use "map" but I don't know how to do.
Next, I wanna save **users** to **model.data** like this. help me.

[image: demo2]

Answer (score 0):

Since you just started using react, try using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) instead of class style components. It's the recommended way.

If you just want to store the data without displaying anything you need somekind of a encapsulated/shared state. For example `redux` or `context` can help you with that. Since context is in-built and easier to use, here is an example:

First create a context

**users-context.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const UsersContext= React.createContext();
```

Now create a custom hook to store your state.

**useUsers.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
export const useUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = () =>{
    //your fetch
  }

  useEffect(()=>{ //equivalent to componentDidMount
    getUsers();
  }, [])

  return {users, setUsers}
}
```

Then provide the context so every component in your app has access to that context.

**App.jsx**

```
import {UsersContext} from "./UsersContext";

const App = () => {

const contextValue = useUsers();

return (
    <div className={'App'}>
      <UsersContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
        <Main/>
      </UsersContext.Provider>
    </div>
   );
 };

 export default App;
```

If you want to use the state in a component, e.g. a profile page do this:

**profile-page.jsx**

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {UsersContext} from "./UsersContext";

const ProfilePage = () => {
const {users} = useContext(UsersContext);

// now you can use it like
console.log(users)

return (...) 
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help^^ but it doesn't work, maybe I'm wrong, can you help me again? My code is here: http://codepad.org/HL9vjlCv

Comment: You are not doing what I did. You are still using classes. :) You should use functional components with hooks. Read more aboute hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html . You can copy paste almost everything I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { UsersContext } from './Components/usersData/users-context';
const getUsers = () => {
  const {users} = UsersContext(UsersContext);
  console.log(users);
  return users;
}
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            data:[]
        }
    data.push(getUsers);`
    }
  }
```